# Skyrim: What are the details on guild ranks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just finished The College of Winterhold (Mage Guild) questline and it was quite short.

In previous TES games, guilds had ranks and the sort. Like the Mages Guild in Oblivion had Associate->Apprentice->Journeyman etc.

I do not see a single thing mentioned about guild ranks in stat menus or the sort and it seems like I went straight from the lowest rank to the highest rank in the College, and I was never any other rank.

How do guild ranks work? For this, and any other guilds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no visible faction ranks anymore. You can become Arch-Mage or whatever, but you cannot see that you are except for owning the Robes.

It is disappointing.

Comment: Only +1'd this because of "It is disappointing." It is rather disappointing isn't it?

Comment: It's probably due to the shortness of the quests and the ambiguity of the rank. Do such and such and you rank up is a bit disappointing...For the Imperial/Stormcloak questline, you are offered a title, but it'll only be used by a few members of the chosen faction